# Labeling axes on Grapher?

Tags: macos

How does one label the axes on the Grapher tool on the Mac? I am currently using OS X El Capitan.

Here's an image of what it looks like right now, with none of the menus s[image: No menus selected.]

And here's the menu with the Object menu selected, as some have suggested:

[image: Object menu selected]

Answer (score 3):

With Grapher open select the Object menu. The bottom selection is "Insert Text". This lets you type a string and move it to wherever you want. Use the arrow cursor to move the text field to where you want it.

An image showing Grapher window with "Insert Text" selected.

[image]

Comment: Hm, I can only Bring to Front, bring to back, etc.

Comment: You have to use the Arrow curser. In the upper left, there are 3 options for curser/

Comment: There are actually only 2 options for curser, an arrow, and a hand. The 3rd option is a magnifying glass. Those 3 are in the upper left corner of Grapher window.

Comment: So the ones over there? http://cubeupload.com/im/qcmptr/ScreenShot20180721at.png

Comment: Yes. The one that looks like an arrow.

Comment: Ok, I selected that one, but the the Object menu still isn't showing anything different.

Comment: Sorry. That won't affect object menu. The last option when you click the object menu is insert text.  What version of Grapher are you using? I'm running 2.6

Comment: I've updated my answer with an image of the grapher window with "Insert Text" selected.

Comment: ah, im working in 3 dimensions, not two.

Comment: Im unsure if that makes a difference and I might be using it wrong, but I think it does here.